# Creating Allure report upon termination of Jenkins job with Pytest, Jenkins, and Playwright

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest, playwright, allure

I have a Jenkins job that runs tests using Pytest in Jenkins.
Currently, if I terminate the Jenkins job in the middle of the run, it doesn't generate the Allure report.

I would like to know how to configure it so that I can get the Allure report even if the job is terminated before completion.

This is the script of the pipeline:

```
@Library('Shared') _
generateJob(
  params: params,
  parameters: parameterize.deployments(['dev']) + [
    string(name: 'X_VERSION', trim: true),
    string(name: 'X_REVISION', trim: true),
    string(name: 'MARKERS', defaultValue: 'sanity', trim: true),
  ],
  lock: [params.DEPLOYMENT],
  envVars: [
    KUBECONFIG: '/tmp/kubeconfig.yaml',
    DEPLOYMENT_IP: "${utils.deploymentIp(params.DEPLOYMENT)}"
  ],
  containers:[
    [name: 'tests', img: "${globals.nexus('dev').url}/tests:${params.X_VERSION}"]
  ],
  stages: [
    [
      'checkoutSCM': ['ref': "${(params.X_REVISION ? params.X_REVISION : params.X_VERSION)}"]
    ],
    {
      stage('Auto Tests') {
        container('tests') {
          minio.downloadFile('kubeconfigs', "kubeconfig-${params.DEPLOYMENT}.yaml", '/tmp/kubeconfig.yaml')
          sh 'cd tests && ./main.sh'
          utils.uploadLogs('tests-logs', "${env.X_VERSION}")
        }
      }
    },
    [allureReport: [results: 'report']]
  ]
)
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

function cleanup {
  pkill kubectl
}
trap cleanup EXIT

function kpf(){
    echo "INFO: Port forward $1"
    kubectl -n default port-forward $1 $2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}

# Prepare
kpf mongo-0 27017:27017

# Run Tests
if [ $MARKERS == 'FOO' ]
then
  pytest -rvP tests -m $MARKERS --alluredir=$WORKSPACE/report/ || true
elif [ $MARKERS == 'ci' ]
then
  pytest -rvP tests -m $MARKERS --alluredir=$WORKSPACE/report/ || true
else
  pytest -rvP tests -m $MARKERS --alluredir=$WORKSPACE/report/ || true
fi

# Jenkins perm
chown -R 1234:1234 $WORKSPACE/report
```

I tried using atexit:

```
def create_allure_report():
    print('hi')
    if os.environ.get('JENKINS'):
        path = os.environ.get('WORKSPACE')
        cmd = f'allure serve {path}'
        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

atexit.register(create_allure_report)
```

And it worked locally (when i terminated the locally run it printet 'hi').

Comment: You can do that with try/catch/finally and put in final block the allure report. Also there is  DSL for the plugin with reportBuildPolicy - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/allure-jenkins-plugin/